# How do I connect interrupts to a function for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c, timer, raspberry-pi, interrupt, bare-metal

I am writing a simple program to test the ARM timer and interrupts on the Raspberry Pi, running baremetal.  Using the ARM timer Masked IRQ register, I have verified that the timer is working as expected and that the interrupt is actually firing.  This is shown in the code below.  I haven't included the register address definitions, but I can if that would be useful.

```
void initTimer(void)
{
    *gpio_fsel1 |= (1 << 18);

    *irq_disable_3 = 0x1; // Disable the timer interrupt for setup
    *arm_timer_load = SYS_FREQ/(250/2); //set load value for 0.5Hz timer
    *arm_timer_reload = SYS_FREQ/(250/2); 
    *arm_timer_div = 0x0F9; //prescale by 250
    *arm_timer_control = 0x003E00A2;
    *arm_timer_irqclr = 1; //clear existing interrupt
    *irq_enable_3 = 0x1; // Enable the timer interrupt
}    

void IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(*irq_pend_base & 0x1) // check interrupt register to see if it's the one we want
        timer_isr();
}

void timer_isr (void)
{
    // change the led state
    if (((*gpio_lev0 & (0x01<<16))>>16)==1){
        *gpio_clr0 = (1<<16);
    }
    else{
        *gpio_set0 = (1<<16);
    }
    //clear interrupt
    *arm_timer_irqclr = 1;
}


int main(void)
{
    initTimer();
    while(1)
    {
        if(*arm_timer_maskedirq) timer_isr();
    }
}
```

The next step is to make the function IRQHandler actually handle the interrupts.  How do I signal to the compiler that this is supposed to be an Interrupt Service Routine?  I am using arm-none-eabi-gcc.

I have tried commenting out the `if(...` line in main() and adding `__attribute__ ((interrupt ("IRQ")));` right after `void IRQHandler(void)`, but the IRQHandler function is never called when the program runs.

I have not done much work with interrupts and ISRs before, and I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Somewhere, there should be code to load the interrupt vector table with IRQHandler address.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  Would this be an added section in the assembly?